# Google Maps SDK for iOSのリバースジオコードのレスポンスの言語指定

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

Google Maps SDK for iOSを使用し、緯度経度から住所を取得しています。
長らく日本語の住所が返されて問題なかったのですが、突如、今日から英語の住所が返されるようになってしまいました。
レスポンスの言語指定は出来るのでしょうか？
また、同じような事象が発生している方がいれば、回避方法を教えて頂きたいです。

一応住所取得部分のソースを載せておきます。

```
// 住所を取得
GMSGeocoder *geocoder = [[GMSGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeCoordinate:coordinate completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse * res, NSError * error) {
    // 結果取得
    GMSReverseGeocodeResult *result = [res firstResult];
    if (result) {
        _latitude = coordinate.latitude;
        _longitude = coordinate.longitude;

        NSLog(@"%@", result);

        // thoroughfareに号が入っていないのでaddressLine2から取得
        NSArray *arrAddress = [[result addressLine2] componentsSeparatedByString:[result subLocality]];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

回答ではありませんが、当方でも同じ現象が発生しているようです。
端末の言語設定を日本語のみにしても英語の住所「Tōkyō-to」のように返却されます。

2017/08/24からいきなり発生したように見えます。

CLGeocoderだと正常に返るようなので、しばらく経っても改善しないようだったらCLGeocoderに置き換えて申請する必要があるかもしれません。

Comment: nosaka.shin様
コメントありがとうございます。
やはり、他でも発生しているんですね。
CLGeocoderの実装も視野に入れたいと思います。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

CLGeocoderを実装し、設定ファイルでGoogleかAppleで切り替えられるように実装してたんですが、先ほど解消したようです。

こういう場合は、下手に対策しないで待ったほうが良いみたいですね。。。